# How to share a host directory between multiple docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, microservices

This is my directory structure [for docker microservices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaANi.png) . What I need to do  is to share certain files from my lib folder which is on my host machine to containers. These are lib files which are required to run the application in both of the containers.This is the content from one of my docker file inside one of the container propinfo-finder

```
FROM alpine:3.3

RUN apk add --update nodejs

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
CMD node index.js
```

I build the docker images using this command `docker build -t nodeapp/premcal .` The build process is successful . Then i use this command to map/mount the directory `bin` to the container to make it run
from the parent directory where bin folder is located

`docker run -v $PWD/lib:/usr/src/app -p 3010:3000 -i nodeapp/premcal`

after running it I am getting this error

```html
module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

The host is a physical Ubuntu machine .

can anybody please tell me how to make this go away . All I have is 2 hrs of experience with node.js and docker environment . 
Thank you .

Comment: Please clarify which excatly javascript file you want to run and what your purpose is. It seems that you are overwriting the image's `/usr/src/app` folder with the content you mount into that directory. Where does the `index.js` come from?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in node.js, but you're attempting to run index.js but don't have an index.js inside your lib folder. If you wanted to run the disco.js, that would be:

```
docker run -v $PWD/lib:/usr/src/app -p 3010:3000 -i \
  davesrepo/dynamo node disco.js
```

Answer (score 0):

run `docker run -v $PWD/lib:/usr/src/app -p 3010:3000 -i davesrepo/dynamo bash` and take a look at the /usr/src/app deriectory.

I guess you have not mounted the lib folder successfully or there is a permission error.

Answer (score 0):

You can share directory between several containers using *data-only containers*.

You can find details [here](http://container42.com/2014/11/18/data-only-container-madness/), [here](http://www.offermann.us/2013/12/tiny-docker-pieces-loosely-joined.html) or even better, [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/).